# How to wrap a blocking method into an async task

Tags: powershell

Here's a small piece of **blocking** code that I want to make **asynchronous**. It simply waits for my input and then outputs it to the screen when I press `enter`.

```
while ($true) {
  $result = [Console]::In.ReadLine()
  "RESULT: $result"
}
```

Here I'm trying to wrap this blocking method `[Console]::In.ReadLine()` to a function that returns a `task`, but `result` property is always empty. What am I missing?

```
function readConsoleWrapper {
  $action = [Action]{
    [Console]::In.ReadLine()
  }
  New-Object System.Threading.Tasks.Task($action)
}

$readLineTask = readConsoleWrapper 

while ($true) {
  sleep -s 1
  $result = $readLineTask.result
  "RESULT: $result"
}
```

Now, I added line `$readLineTask.start()` and `Write $readLineTask`, here's error

```
Exception              : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
                         System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: There is no Runspace available to
                         run scripts in this thread. You can provide one in the DefaultRunspace property of the
                         System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The script block you attempted to
                         invoke was:
                             [Console]::In.ReadLine()

                            at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetContextFromTLS()
                            at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(Object dollarUnder,
                         Object dollarThis, Object[] args)
                            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
                            --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                         ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidOperationException: There is
                         no Runspace available to run scripts in this thread. You can provide one in the
                         DefaultRunspace property of the System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.Runspace type. The
                         script block you attempted to invoke was:
                             [Console]::In.ReadLine()

                            at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.GetContextFromTLS()
                            at System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeAsDelegateHelper(Object dollarUnder,
                         Object dollarThis, Object[] args)
                            at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward to me, you want to run things in separate runspaces but didn't create a runspace pool to do it with. I don't think what you are trying to do is as simple as you are hoping.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, here's a solution using C# (greek to me), but it seems like a simple thing